# jQuery create select list options from JSON, not happening as advertised?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

How come this doesn't work (operating on an empty select list `<select id="requestTypes"></select>`

```
$(function() {

        $.getJSON("/RequestX/GetRequestTypes/", showRequestTypes);

    }
    );


    function showRequestTypes(data, textStatus) {

        $.each(data,
            function() {

                var option = new Option(this.RequestTypeName, this.RequestTypeID);
                // Use Jquery to get select list element
                var dropdownList = $("#requestTypes");

                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    dropdownList.add(option);
                }

                else {

                    dropdownList.add(option, null);

                }
            }
            );

        }
```

But this does:

- Replace:

  `var dropdownList = $("#requestTypes");`
- With plain old javascript:

  `var dropdownList = document.getElementById("requestTypes");`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$("#requestTypes")` returns a jQuery object that contains all the selected elements.  You are attempting to call the `add()` method of an individual element, but instead you are calling the `add()` method of the jQuery object, which does something very different.

In order to access the DOM element itself, you need to treat the jQuery object as an array and get the first item out of it, by using `$("#requestTypes")[0]`.

Answer (score 9):

By default, jQuery selectors return the jQuery object. Add this to get the DOM element returned:

```
 var dropdownList = $("#requestTypes")[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

For stuff like this, I use [texotela's select box plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/) with its simple ajaxAddOption function.