# JAVASCRIPT: data structure instead of arrays

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'm building a form where a description field changes it's content based on the input (onchange event) of the form. I have multiple input fields and each have their own description.

What I have been doing in the past is for each field (this is a very small examle):

```
var wisdom  = [' ', 'Seeker of Wisdom', 'Collector of Wisdom', 'Devotee of Wisdom', 'Devourer of Wisdom', 'Font of Wisdom', 'Oracle of Wisdom', 'Source of Wisdom'];
var wisdomp = [0, 100, 250, 550, 1200, 2500, 5000, 10000, 10000];
```

But initializing all these vars on the page doesn't seem right to me and creates a huge block of text. That's why I thought it would be better to read this data from an external file. I couldn't find a javascript file reader though.

*Is there any better structure or method to keep and retrieve data using javascript?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fact, you can use json to describe a k/v structure that seems to match your need:

{' ':0,'Seeker of Wisdom':100,'Collector of Wisdom':250 } and so on

note that you can also use nested structures as well using this notation.

see: http://www.json.org

Comment: Thank you, that should work in creating my variables more dynamic and reduce space. Is it actually OK to initialize all these vars on the relevant page?

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery create select list options from JSON, not happening as advertised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94674/jquery-create-select-list-options-from-json-not-happening-as-advertised) is more popular alternative to mentioned problem. would not bet on it being any better

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Did you also propose to use JSON, or a variant of it?

Comment: yep, same json. given URL looks at it with more detail